# Build abelian group containing a set $K$ under an associative, commutative operation $*$ with an identity but the inverses are not always in $K$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, semigroups, magma

We are given a set K of elements and an operation *** . For every element in the set, there exists an inverse element (not necessarily in the set). There are three (additional) rules:

1) K contains *e* (neutral element) such that for every x: x *** *e* = *e* * x = x

2) K is associative

3) K is commutative

The task is to build an abelian group G such that G contains K
OR to prove that it is impossible.

The task seems to be intuitively simple, but the concrete proof seems to be unobvious.

Comment: I, be submitted an edit. Yes, e is "truly" neutral, and an inverse element exists for every element.

Comment: Why didn't you list the existence of inverses among the rules in the first place?

Comment: Fixed my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily possible, since you have no guarantee of the existence of inverses. Specifically, if $K$ is the set of integers and * is multiplication, then it satisfies all three rules. Alternatively, if $K = \{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and * is addition, you also have all three rules satisfied.

What you have with those three rules is called a (commutative) *monoid*. Remove condition 1) and you have a semigroup.

---

**Edit:** After adding the rule that each element has an inverse, your (now four) rules are *exactly* the rules of an abelian group.

Comment: But (a) the inverse is not necessarily in the set and (b) x1*x2 might not lie in the set

Comment: OK, so we're not even assuming that the operation is closed. Well, then, there is really nothing more you can do unless you have a concrete example in front of you.